# What is a linear condition on the coeffcients of a quadric?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

Suppose that we have a quadric $ Q. $ What does it mean to say that the requirement that $ Q = \lbrace f = 0 \rbrace $ passes through a given point is a linear condition on the coefficients of $ f$?

My apologies if this is quite basic. I feel that this is mostly a matter of terminology.

Comment: It means that if you write the coefficients of $Q$ into some vector $v$, then that condition can be written as $Av = b$ (or maybe $Av = 0$?) for some matrix $A$ and constant vector $b$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Question: does $$  a x^2 +  b xy + c y^2 = 0  $$ pass through $$ x=7, y=-2 \; ? $$

Answer: does
$$  49 a - 14 b + 4 c = 0 \; ? $$

Comment: Remark: this also shows that a quadratic is uniquely determined y three point (in general position).